# sudo -i but keep current working directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, redhat, command-line-interface

When use `sudo -i` I will simulate login as root, and current working directory will be jumped to /root.

Is it possible not to jump and keep the working directory unchanged?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you need to simulate an initial log in, you can use `sudo -s` to just get a root shell.

Comment: Thanks..seems the man page of sudo suck.. e.g.        -s [command]
                   The -s (shell) option runs the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified in passwd(5).  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution.
                   Otherwise, an interactive shell is executed.

Answer (score 3):

-s option does not allow me to run commands which can be found only after user login (PATH is updated in the .bash_profile)

Answer 'Joel K' is cause of error. So correct way is:

```
sudo -i -- bash -c "cd '$PWD'; echo"
```

Use your own command instead of echo.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo -i "cd `/bin/pwd` ; /bin/bash"
```

Comment: Fails for me with `-bash: cd /path/to/current/dir ; /bin/bash: No such file or directory`